# Replacing an adapter with a car battery

Tags: power-supply, power

I'm wanting to run my Wi-Fi off solar rather than mains power or going through inverter, its adapter says it puts out 12 VDC @ 1.5 A. can I connect it straight to the battery? The thing is, the solar controller regularly pushes the battery up to 14.6 VDC or will I need a volt regulator.

Comment: so your question really is `will my WiFi device run from 14.6 Vdc?` ... check the device specs

Comment: If the battery is lead-acid (SLA), 14.6 V is a bit high for maximum service life. Most are designed to be charged to 13.7 V or so. If you're concerned, put a Si diode or two in series - each will drop 0.7 V.

Comment: the battery is a 300ah lithium battery, the solar controller does a bulk charge to 14.7vdc then lets it go back to about 13.8vdc, what I'm asking is would the Wi-Fi router handle 14.7vdc as it's got a 240ac adaptor putting out 12vdc @ 1.5a.

Comment: We don't know (a) which device it is, and even if we did, we don't know (b) how it is designed and with what specs. So it is impossible to say if any 12V device or your specifically can safely take 14.7V in, without reverse engineering the schematics and components it has.

Comment: What PDP11 says. Damage **MAY** happen and you cannot tell. An LDO (low dropout voltage regulator) will solve this. Or an eg Amazon 10-20V in, 12V out  power supply (test first) . || OR add 4 series diodes and 1 16V 1000 uF cap at the router, see if it ALWAYS works OK and measure voltage. Remove diode / diodes to raise voltage. || 1N400x are cheap and available. Use two in parallel x N sets in series as required.

Answer (score 2):

Generally not a good idea to make a direct connection.

A WiFi Modem/Router/Access Point is not guaranteed to have a fuseable link in the supply line as the power adapter will provide the overcurrent protection. An adapter will have a limited ability to supply a current greater than the rated value. Under fault conditions a battery can supply a much greater current than the adapter and may cause significant damage to PCB tracks plus the active and passive components. Therefore a suitably rated fuse should be included in the circuit e.g. 1.5A fast blow fuse.

Generally the manufacturers are not going to publish the upper voltage limit in addition to the operating voltage. If it is a DC adapter then a Low Dropout (LDO) regulator, diodes or resistor can be added to provide some form of overvoltage protection. My preference would be an LDO.

Comment: thanks, i was planning on adding a 1.5a fuse, but if the Wi-Fi router is asking for the 1.5a @ 12vdc and it starts coming in at 14.7vdc could it overheat or blow something? i do have a 12vdc led light dimmer, but i think it uses PWM to control volts so it would fluctuate still I guess.

Comment: Heat is one problem as your device will not have a fan and will rely on passive cooling in an enclosed space with limited air flow.

Comment: @PDP11 Why do you assume a device such as a Wifi adapter taking 12V would have an LDO? Anyway, you make a good point. The supply might be a "linear" or "switch mode" type. We don't know that either. The Wifi adapter may damage immediately if connected to 14.7V.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I don't assume that the WiFi adapter has an LDO, I'm suggesting that an LDO be added.

Comment: @PDP11 then you need to start editing your original question with the details you keep putting in comments - that is not the place for them.

Comment: @Solar Mike - I was answering requests for clarification posted in the comments here and comments to the question by Justme that don't really change the answer provided. As pointed out by Justme there is not enough detail in the question to know if heat or overvoltage will even be an issue. Although I did change the text from "can be used" to "can be added" to correct my English. I don't do that much posting on Stackexchange so unshure where answers to points of clarification should go. I don't understand why I would be asked to change the Author's question.

Comment: think i found something that will work ...https://www.jaycar.com.au/multi-voltage-regulated-adaptor-module/p/AA0372?pos=5&queryId=ff619fba65739e1fd98ec8e941abe080

Comment: @burtonreed The Jaycar decide looks suitable. HOWEVER far chepr would be to try my diodes suggestion made two days ago in a comment on your answer.

Comment: an update if interested , i got that jaycar adaptor and it was suppling 12.5vdc  with 13.1vdc coming in, as the incoming voltage increased so did the adaptors output. i then tested its 240vac adaptor and it was putting out 13.1vdc and not the said 12vdc it said so i proceeded with the install ,i then remembered volt drop with cable length so just added more cable till it was putting out 13vdc max with battery at 14.6v. so far so good ,its working great ,I'm thinking maybe its like 220vac- 240vac supply range and maybe i didn't even need to worry  ,thanks anyway.